# Find the least positive integer $n$ such that $\overline{1234567891011 \ldots n}$ is divisible by $15015$

Tags: number-theory

> Find the least positive integer $n$ such that $\overline{1234567891011 \ldots n}$ is divisible by $15015$.

First note that $15015 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$. Thus, $n$ must be a multiple of $5$. Also, we must have $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ so either $n$ or $n+1$ is divisible by $3$. For divisibility by $11$, note that $9-8+7-6+5-4+3-2+1 \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$. For additional numbers in $10,11,\ldots,19$ added we add $-1,-1,0,2,5,9,\ldots$, but I didn't see how to continue with this. I also didn't see how to use the divisibility rules for $7$ and $13$.

I checked that $n = 15,30,45,60$ don't work but didn't see how to find the smallest possible $n$.

Comment: Maybe thinking about how you get from one number to the next... You multiply by a power of $10$, then add a number. It might lead to some nice pattern, at least modulo $11$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it by hand, but running a script gives me $n=16140$.

Comment: for divisibility of $3$, it seems you are adding $n$s, whereas you must consider their digits...

Comment: I found this by computer:
8222230376364444316694087125675739082534307511350670 x 15015=
123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930310050

May be the least number is 0050